# BeautifulSoupで抽出したタグリストからテキストのみをリスト形式で抽出したい

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("********************")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

class = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "word")
```

このままだと、スクレイピングで該当したものがhtmlのタグに囲まれたままリストに保管されます。

タグは必要がないので、タグを削除した状態でリスト形式で保管したいです。

Answer (score 1):

テキストだけで良いのであれば、以下で出来るでしょう。

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("********************")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

wordclass = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "word")

wordlist = [x.text for x in wordclass]

print(wordlist)
```

Comment: テキストのみの保管ができました。
ただ、"¥n"改行コードが一部含まれています。改行コードも削除するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか。

Comment: `wordlist = [x.replace("\n"," ") for x in wordlist]`
同じ要領で改行コードも削除できました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: `wordlist = [x.text.replace("\n"," ") for x in wordclass]` というふうに一度にやることも出来ます。